# comparator problems

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

While I was playing with some redstone tried to make a money system to sell iron. However when I power the command block with a button, the comparator after it stays on.

the command being run is:

```
/clear @p minecraft:iron_ingot 0 5
```

and then a comparator leads to:

```
/scoreboard players add @p Dollars 10
```

So how do I turn off the comparator?

Comment: I'm pretty sure comparators output based on the successful command count, not whether a particular command was successful.

Comment: There isn't a good way to "turn off" a comparator.  The command block still has a success value until it fails.

Comment: See my answer here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220548/how-do-i-make-the-comparator-work-and-then-stop/220550#220550

Answer (score 0):

If the command returns successful, a blockdata value called `SucessCount` is true, and until the command returns false, it will remain true. So along with the `/scoreboard` command, run `/blockdata [Command block X Y Z] {SucessCount:0}` and  `/setblock [Comparator X Y Z] unpowered_comparator`

Answer (score -4):

have you tried scoreboard?
I would do:
/scoreboard players set @p sell 1
On A Fill Clock
/clear @p[score_sell_min=1] iron_ingot 0 5
/scoreboard objectives add @p[score_sell_min=1] Dollars 10
/scoreboard players set @p[score_sell_min=1] sell 0
Hopefully that would work.
I havnt tried it but i wish you luck

Comment: Please inform yourself to how formulate and format an answer on this site. An answer should not contain questions by temlselves and please keep formatting in mind.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to test a command before you post it here.  We prefer answers that *solve* the problem, not just guess at it.

Comment: @TML Please take the tour: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour